# debug node cluster using 'node-inspector'

Tags: node.js, debugging, gulp, mocha.js, node-inspector

I am trying to debug node tests, written in mocha, which are running using [Gulp Spawn Mocha](https://github.com/knpwrs/gulp-spawn-mocha).

My Gulp code looks something like this:

```
return gulp.src(mochaGlobs, {read: false})
  .pipe(plugins.spawnMocha({
    reporter: !inTeamCity() ? 'mocha-env-reporter' : '',
    timeout: 30000,
    execArgv: ['--debug-port=5859']
  }))
```

I am getting the same error (no matter which port I use):

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::{port}

After reading a little about this, I understand that the child process is using the same debug port as the main process. (see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3469#issuecomment-149961323) for an example/solution.

I tried adding `execArgv: ['--debug-port=5859']` and `execArgv: ['--debug-brk=5859']` and `execArgv: ['--debug=5859']`, all gave me the same error..

What am I doing wrong? How can I change child process debug port?